# How to enable DNS over HTTPS (DoH) on Pop!_OS 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, dns, pop-os

I recently started using Quad9 DNS and now want to enable DoH(not DoT). I was looking to enable it without any third party software (This is already possible on Windows). All the guides I can find are for DNS over TLS.

`systemd-resolved` does have a configuration for DoT:

```
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
```

I do have the option to enable DoH in Firefox, but I want to enable it system-wide.

Is there a way to achieve something similar for DoH using `systemd-resolved` or any other built-in program?

Answer (score 0):

`systemd-resolved` does *not* support DoH, a feature request is pending: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8639

For a system resolver supporting DoH I'd recommend `https-dns-proxy`: https://github.com/aarond10/https_dns_proxy It's lightweight, reliable and has minimum dependencies.

---

Quad9 supports DoT as well. Why do you insist on DoH when DoT is available? Makes no sense to me. Besides DoH relies on working name resolution to initiate which makes it a tad less secure than DoT.

Here's my `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/resolved.conf`:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8#dns.google 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
Cache=no-negative
# Never fallback
FallbackDNS=
```

Remove `8.8.8.8#dns.google 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com`  above if you want to use Quad9 resolvers only.

Comment: I do realise that DoT is supported, but it so happens that DoT is often blocked on many public networks for Eg the ones in my uni. They cannot block DoH as it would render most HTTPS sites unusable.

Comment: systemd-resolved does *not* support DoH, a feature request is pending: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8639 Please use `https-dns-proxy` for that: https://github.com/aarond10/https_dns_proxy It's very lightweight, reliable and has minimum dependencies.